# MATLAB- Adding Terms In An Array

Tags: matlab

I am fairly new to programming, and I am have a difficult time with finishing a function to use in my homework assignment. Below I have the code for a function that is intended to take the month entered subtract 1 from it, and add the number of days that are entered. Returning the total number of day.  For example, if m=4, days= 3, then it would go through the for loop and add 31+28+31+4.  I would greatly appreciate your help.  Thank you for your time!

```
function bday=daysinmonth(m, d)

    array=[31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31];

    for i=1:m-1

        md=sum(array(i))

    end   

    %sum=md+d  
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array holding the number of days for each months is a good starting point. Then I don't understand why you iterate up to the month. What you are looking for is the sum up to the current month, so something like:

```
md=sum(array(1:m-1));
```

And yes, then you can add the current day to the accumulated days from previous months with

```
sum=md+d;
```

You also want to make sure, that you return the this number with

```
function sum=daysinmonth(m, d)
```